# Gatling Cannot resolve symbol 'http'

Tags: java, scala, maven, gatling

I am having an issue specifically with the 'http' imports shown below

```
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.http;
import static io.gatling.javaapi.http.HttpDsl.status;
```

They are not recognised in the following block:

```
 .exec(http("${testType}")
                    .post(RequestBuilder.launch1p0)
                    .formParam(LTIParam.context_id.name(), "${district_pid}")
            )
```

My simplified version of my pom.xml looks like this:

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <gatling.version>3.8.4</gatling.version>
        <gatling-maven-plugin.version>4.2.7</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
        <scala-logging_2.11.version>3.7.2</scala-logging_2.11.version>
        <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.7.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
        <performance-base.version>1.0</performance-base.version>
    </properties>


<dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <plugin>
              <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
              <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
```

I have tried reloading the maven projects, deleting the gatling-core.jar files and retrying

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

If anyone knows why it has an issue with this specific import, and not the following:

```
import io.gatling.javaapi.core.ChainBuilder;

import static io.gatling.javaapi.core.CoreDsl.*;
```

please explain to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you provided is very suspicious.

You mention that you have in your pom.xml:

```xml
<scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
<scala-logging_2.11.version>3.7.2</scala-logging_2.11.version>
```

but those properties are not used in what you provided.

If you are really pulling those libraries, those versions are completely wrong and break your build.

- Gatling 3.8 requires Scala 2.13 (since 3.5)
- you're trying to force Scala 2.12.8 => not compatible
- scala-logging_2.11 means "compiles for Scala 2.11"

3 different and incompatible Scala versions!

You should be pulling Scala 2.13.10 (but that shouldn't be necessary) and scala-logging_2.13 3.9.5.

Comment: I have tried updating the versions but there was no change. It should be mentioned that this code is code that is being converted from Scala to Java so there shouldn't be a need for any Scala dependencies. If the Scala dependencies have been removed and the error is still occurring, is there any other possibility as to why this issue is happening? Thanks

Comment: No idea what your exact problem is. You should provide a proper reproducer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Maybe there's a corrupted jar in your local maven cache. You should try removing the `~/.m2/repository/io/gatling` directory.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by adding the pom.xml as a Maven project. Perhaps that was the issue all along :)

Comment: Do you mean you didn't import your maven project as a maven project in IntelliJ?